# Firebase Database serialize int to enum?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, enums, kotlin

It it to possible to serialize int/long to enum ?
Previously my model was something like this:

```
class A(var style: Int = STYLE_NORMAL) : Parcelable, Observable{...}
```

Where style value could be either

```
const val STYLE_NORMAL : Int = 0
```

or

```
const val STYLE_CUSTOM : Int = 1
```

Now I decided that it will be better if I wrap it with enum.

```
enum class Style {
    @SerializedName("0") NORMAL,
    @SerializedName("1") CUSTOM
}
```

So my model now look like this:

```
class A(var style: Style = Style.NORMAL) : Parcelable, Observable{...}
```

And everything works fine except that Firebase cann't parse already stored objects on previous model to the new one, and this line

```
snapshot.getValue(A::java.class)
```

Throws exception

> E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException:
>   **Expected a String** while **deserializing to enum** class
>   com.stasbar.models.A$Style but got a class java.lang.Long

I understand that the issue is that Firebase can parse only Strings to enums.
Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I'm using workaround that uses @IntDef annotation instead of enum. But I will keep the question open for enum solution

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@IntDef(Style.NORMAL, Style.CUSTOM)
annotation class StyleDef


object Style {
    const val NORMAL: Long = 0
    const val CUSTOM: Long = 1
}
```

and my model become

```
class A(@StyleDef var style: Long = Style.NORMAL) : Parcelable, Observable{...}
```